# JavaScript : what does it mean to have brackets () after array[]?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS, and I have read a code that contains this line.

```
this.myArray[index](this._sender, args);
```

I wonder what it means?

Comment: `this.myArray` might be containing function references, thus `this.myArray[index]` fetches function reference then invokes it using arguments

Comment: That looks like the array value is used to trigger a function hence the argument "this._sender" "args" `(this._sender, args)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that this array item is a function, and it is being called with arguments `this._sender` and `args`.

In this example, I declare an array, push a single-argument function to it, and call it.

```js
var arr = [];

arr.push(function(str) {
  document.body.innerHTML = "Hey, " + str;
});

arr[0]("Your name");
```

Answer (score 0):

that means that the myArray[index] is the element of myArray that is function that is why it requires 2 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, functions are first class objects so they can be passed around/referenced, stored, and accessed like any other value.

```
var myArray = [];
var myFunction = function(name) {
  console.log("Hello, " + name + "!");
};

myFunction('World');

myArray[0] = myFunction;
myArray[0]('again');

function addDefault(func, defaultValue) {
  return function(name) {
    name = name ? name : defaultValue;

    func(name);
  }
}
var myFunctionWithDefault = addDefault(myFunction, 'stranger');
myFunctionWithDefault();
myFunctionWithDefault('goodbye');
```

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/wubuye/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to following snippet:

```
var myClass = function () {
    this._a = 5;
    var index = arguments[0] || 0;

    this.myArray = [
        function (a, b) {
            console.log(a, b);
        },
        function (a, b) {
            console.log(a, b);
        }
    ];
    this.myArray[index](this._a, arguments);
};

var obj = new myClass(1, 2, 3);//5  [1, 2, 3]
```